# Python Floating Point Error when using SCP plug-in (QGIS 3.6)

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, scp

I receive a python error every time i try to save a temporary ROI to training input in the Semi-automatic classification plug-in in QGIS 3.6.  I'm unable to add any training ROI to training input.

python error below

i've tried:

1. uninstalling, and reinstalling the plugin
2. installing a new version of qgis (was originally in 3.4)
3. used other images

Any one have a similar problem and found a solution?

Error Message below:

```
2019-05-21T19:02:02     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/Users/ncu116/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\dock\scpdock.py", line 2503, in saveROItoShapefile
          cfg.utls.calculateSignature(cfg.shpLay, cfg.bandSetsList[cfg.bndSetNumber][8], [self.ROILastID], cfg.ROIMacroID, cfg.ROIMacroClassInfo, cfg.ROIID, cfg.ROIInfo, 50, 40, "No", "No", UID)
          File "C:/Users/ncu116/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 1739, in calculateSignature
          ROIsize = cfg.utls.getROISize(bX, 1, rStat[0], rStat[1])
          File "C:/Users/ncu116/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 5672, in getROISize
          s = ( (a >= min) & (a              FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
```